# Heroku - How to load models from AWS S3 bucket?

Tags: python, flask, amazon-s3, heroku, stanford-nlp

I developed an application that uses Python + Flask + Stanford CoreNLP. The Stanford CoreNLP pipeline needs to know where the models are stored locally on the computer such as this

```py
currentDirectory = os.getcwd()
models_dir = currentDirectory + '/models'
pipeline = stanfordnlp.Pipeline(models_dir=models_dir, lang='en', use_gpu=(not cpu))
```

Given the space limits of the Heroku server, I thought of using the AWS s3 service to store the models but I don't see how to load the models (from Heroku server to AWS S3 bucket) since I have to provide the **local path** for the **local folder** with the models.

Do you have an idea of how to solve the problem? Right now, the only solution I see is to download the models directly from the AWS s3 bucket to the Heroku server but this will not work due to slowness and limit space on the server.

Comment: Yeah, looks like you will have to download the models from S3. Can you bump up the size of your Heroku server and add storage to it?

Comment: @pistolpete the maximum slug size is 500 mb. This way, I really have to store the models elsewhere. I guess that downloading is impractical considering that it would have to be download the files every time the pipeline was needed. Is there another solution that I don't have in mind?

Comment: How large are the models? Maybe Heroku isn't the best platform here?

Comment: Each of the models is greater than 100 MB. Suggestions for other platforms?